# Why sometimes Apple Accelerate framework is slow?

Tags: swift, macos, loops, simd, accelerate-framework

---

I am playing with C and Swift 3.0 code using vecLib and [Accelerate framework](https://developer.apple.com/reference/accelerate) from Apple as  dynamic lib + my code in **C lang** based project and **Swift** playground.

And in situation with calling Apple's wrapper from *framework* of SIMD instruction with 1 or < 4 elements computation function like `vvcospif()` from *framework* is slower than simple standart `cos(x * PI)` when functions calls from loop near 1.000 times as example.

I know about difference between `vvcospif()` and `cos()`, I should use exactly `vvcospif()` for `x * PI`.

Example in playground, you can just copy code and run it:

```swift
import Cocoa
import Accelerate

func cosine_interpolate(alpha: Float, a: Float, b: Float) -> Float {
    let ft: Float = alpha * 3.1415927;
    let f: Float = (1 - cos(ft)) * 0.5;

    return a + f*(b - a);
}

var start: Date = NSDate() as Date

var interp: Float;

for index in 0..<1000 {
   interp = cosine_interpolate(alpha: 0.25, a: 1.0, b: 0.75)
}

var end = NSDate();
var timeInterval: Double = end.timeIntervalSince(start);

print("cosine_interpolate in \(timeInterval) seconds")

func fast_cosine_interpolate(alpha: Float, a: Float, b: Float) -> Float {
    var x: Float = alpha
    var count: Int32 = 1

    var result: Float = 0
    vvcospif(&result, &x, &count)

    let SINSIN_HALF_X: Float = (1 - result) * 0.5;

    return a + SINSIN_HALF_X * (b - a);
}

start = NSDate() as Date

for index in 0..<1000 {
    interp = fast_cosine_interpolate(alpha: 0.25, a: 1.0, b: 0.75)
}

end = NSDate();
timeInterval = end.timeIntervalSince(start);

print("fast_cosine_interpolate in \(timeInterval) seconds")
```

My question is:

### Why `vvcospif()` is slow in this example?

May be because `vvcospif()` it is wrapper under Objective-C runtime and converting data structures / copying of memory from Intel SIMD -> Objective-C -> Swift runtime is slower then tiny `cos()`?

### I also have performance issue with C code +

```c
#include <Accelerate/Accelerate.h>

vvcospif(resultVector, inputVector, &count);
```

when `inputVector` and `resultVector` is small arrays with 1 or 2 elements or just float variable, and calls in loop with ~ 1.000.000 times.

`cos(x * PI)` computation time near 20 ms.

and

`vvcospif(x)` with processing one `float` or `float array[2]` - computation time near 80 ms! Where is Acceleration? :)

Yes, in Xcode I use compiler `-O -whole-module-optimization` optimisation with whole module opt. enabled.

Comment: I assume that `a + f(b - a)` in the first method should be `a + f*(b - a)`? – I ran your code on a MacBook and got the following timings: cosine_interpolate: 0.74 milli seconds, fast_cosine_interpolate: 0.1 milli seconds.

Comment: Thank you, this was mistake in code with f * action. On my mac mini:

cosine_interpolate in 0.461017966270447 seconds
fast_cosine_interpolate in 0.545050024986267 seconds

Comment: `-o` sets the output file name.  `-O3 -ffast-math` enables full optimization.  Does that explain your times being 3 orders of magnitude slower than Martin's?

Comment: No, I updated question and fix mistake with -O: in Xcode was selected default optimisation for Release and Debug, also this results was in default Swift 3.0 and Xcode 8, Sierra playground. In playground "project" I can't select optimisation flags...

Comment: `vvcospif` is a vForce function. vForce deals with vectors of arbitrary length, which creates a bit of overhead, therefore it is not recommended for extremely short vectors. Apple itself [recommends](http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/713xcx4xtaue02i1tvk0kpvarvo/713/713.pdf): "Consider using vForce when more than 16 elements". For scalar uses, consider using `__cospi{f}`, available from iOS 7 and OS X 10.9 according to the source already cited.

Comment: Please see these recent tweets https://twitter.com/kelvindotchan/status/1086417363031908352?s=21 https://twitter.com/kelvindotchan/status/1086423804367200256?s=21 I performed exactly one vForce call to compute abs(a big big vector) and I am surprised Jeremy’s library, which is basically doing a loop using pointers instead of swift array access, actually beat Accelerate slightly. Although this is an adhoc test, I really suspect Accelerate is not as fast as it should be. Any tips? Note that I didn’t do any special compiler flag tricks for his library neither.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*For a more detailed discussion with examples, see ["Introduction to Fast Bezier (and Trying the Accelerate.framework)"](http://robnapier.net/fast-bezier-intro).*

The first, fundamental problem is that non-inlined function calls are extremely expensive. You don't want function calls if you can possibly help it in performance-critical code. Within a module, the compiler can often inline functions for you, and parts of stdlib can be inlined for you. But when you start crossing module barriers, Swift generally cannot optimize out the call.

The point of SIMD functions is that you set up all your data in the right format, and then call them just one time. That way the cost of the function call is made up by the SIMD optimized code you're calling.

But remember, you don't have to call into Accelerate to get SIMD optimizations. The compiler is perfectly capable of noticing you've written a loop and turning it into an inline SIMD algorithm itself (and it does this all the time). So for many simple problems, the compiler is going to win anyway. Think about it: if calling `vvcospif` with a count of 1 were faster than calling `cos`, wouldn't they just implement `cos` that way?

I haven't played with your code much, but if you want to improve its performance with Accelerate, you want to think about how to arrange all your input data so you can call `vvcospif` one time with a large N. It's quite possible in that case that it will be much faster that a loop (since `cos` is not trivial).

If you want an example of Accelerate in practice, and how you need to organize your data, see [PinchText](https://github.com/rnapier/richtext-coretext/blob/master/PinchText/Classes/PinchTextLayer.m). This code is computing offsets for a page full of a few thousand glyphs based on up to 10 touches in real-time, with animations (see [PinchText.mov](https://github.com/rnapier/richtext-coretext/blob/master/PinchText/PinchText.mov) for what the result looks like). In particular look at `adjustViewPositions:count:forTouchPoint:`. Notice how `count` is large, and the data is transformed step by step with no loops. Even throwing in a (very expensive) ObjC method call into that method doesn't matter very much because it's only made one time. Getting rid of function calls in loops is a huge part of performance programming.

Comment: In addition to answering the question, you bring up a great point about what Casey Muratori calls "non-pessimization," which would lead most programmers to faster code even without explicit optimizations, namely simply avoiding multiple calls to unnecessary overhead in the first place.  Imagine trying to call SIMD instructions, through a full function call, one operand at a time, with the function call _inside_ a loop...